# How to update a function in multiple Access databases (MDB, ACCDB)

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, ms-office

We have a large number of access databases that contain a number of common functions.  We need to make a small change to one of the functions, and are looking for a way to automate this via scripting, etc.  Is there any way to get at the VBA code inside an Access database, and make a change to it?

I have used ADOX before from PS or VBS to be able to list tables, views and queries, but it does not expose the VBA code in its API.

~bp

Answer (score 0):

If the code changes are always in a module with a consistent name then you can simply remove the existing module and reimport the new version in all the projects you need to apply the change.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VBE.aspx

The above link posts information on how to import modules into a VBA project.  So simple case of looping through your multiple databases and removing the module and importing the latest version.

If the code changes are located in different module names, you can open each database and loop through the modules to search for the string.  The functions you'll need are listed here (depending on the style of change, it'll most likely be some combination of `Find` and `ReplaceLine`)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223124%28v=office.11%29.aspx